# how can I open a popup html file from within a Chrome extension popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am quite new to Chrome extensions. I am trying to do something very very simple: open a popup.html page from within the popup of my chrome extension.

In my native default chrome extension popup I have placed a button. when clicking on this button I want to open another html popup which would have different content.

here is my manifest.json :

```json
{
  "name": "CheatSheets",
  "description": "cheatsheet extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting","tabs"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  }
}
```

and here is my popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="git_Sheet">git sheet</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then, my popup.js file :

```js
let gitSheet = document.getElementById("git_Sheet");

gitSheet.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: ShowGitSheet,
  });
});

function ShowGitSheet() {
  chrome.browserAction.openPopup({
    popup: "git_popup.html"
});
}
```

Comment: Don't use chrome.browserAction.openPopup. Use `window.open` or chrome.windows.create({url: '...', type: 'popup'})

Comment: yes i have found out in the meantime, i have used chrome.windows.create !! thank you !

Comment: I didn't even knew that `browserAction.openPopup` existed, I looked on google and found that only **firefox** supports it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the comments up here^^, i was able to make this very simple chrome extension function, i only changed my popup.js file :

```js
let gitSheet = document.getElementById("git_Sheet");
let CLI_Sheet =document.getElementById("CLI_Sheet");

gitSheet.addEventListener("click", async () => {

  chrome.windows.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popups/git_popup.html"), type: 
  "popup", height : 800, width : 500 });
});

CLI_Sheet.addEventListener("click", async () => {

  chrome.windows.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popups/terminal_popup.html"), type: 
  "popup", height : 800, width : 500 });
});
```